# Reading parquet files in GCP using wildcards in spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, wildcard

I am trying to read parquet files using spark,
if I want to read the data for June, I'll do the following:

```
"gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month=6/file.parquet"
```

if I want to read the data for all the months, I'll do the following:

```
"gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month=6/file.parquet"
```

if I want to read the first two days of May:

```
"gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month=5/day={1,2}file.parquet"
```

if I want to read November and December:

```
"gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month={11,12}/file.parquet"
```

you get the idea... but what if I have a dictionary of month, days   key, value pairs..
for example `{1: [1,2,3], 4: [10,11,12,13]}` --> which means that I need to read the days [`1,2,3]` from `January`, and the days `[10,11,12,13]` from `April`. how would I reflect that as a wildcard to the path.

Thank you

Comment: It looks that the folder structure is already partitioned and so I think you can simply read whole data with some filter is enough. The filter will push down and only read for that specific partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of paths to DataFrameReader:

```
months_dict = {1: [1, 2, 3], 4: [10, 11, 12, 13]}

paths = [
    f"gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month={k}/day={{{','.join([str(d) for d in v])}}}/*.parquet"
    for k, v in months_dict.items()
]

print(paths)
# ['gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month=1/day={1,2,3}/*.parquet', 'gs://bucket/Data/year=2021/month=4/day={10,11,12,13}/*.parquet']

df = spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```